# Как написать бота для майнкрафт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, поиск-библиотек

Может, кто-то знает, как написать бота для Minecraft? Может есть какая-либо библиотека или где-то описан API для взаимодействия Python и Minecraft?

Comment: pip install malmo

Comment: @ThisIsName Не работает